# Creating a Scheduled Task that runs forever on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, scheduled-task

When I create a scheduled task, I do so via command line:

```
schtasks.exe /Create /TN "startup-script" /TR "C:\startup.bat" /RU taskuser 
    /RP taskpasswd /SC ONLOGON
```

The idea is that this task run forever. The batch opens a java process that is never meant to end.

I've used ONLOGON, as the machine auto-logs in as *taskuser*.

All this works fine, for about 72 hours, after which the Duration flag kicks in and ends the process.
Windows XP doesn't have the **/DU** flag on command line - is there an alternative method to creating a task that is meant to run from a system startup (doesn't even require logon) and runs forever, without touching a GUI?

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this on XP? What is the java process?

Answer (score 2):

Are you tied to Schtasks.exe?

You can use a cron type process launcher (there are many - here are a couple):

- http://cronw.sourceforge.net/
  http://www.kalab.com/freeware/pycron/pycron.htm
  http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm

Another possibility is to use srvany.exe from the 2k3 resource kit (runs on XP) and turn startup.bat into a service which will be running at the point netlogon starts.

Rob

Comment: +1 Run it as a Service.

Comment: Java programs are quite tough to run as a service, in my experience and reading.

Comment: Rob, Andy - like mfinni said - running a java app as a service - any thoughts?

Comment: If you want a service wrapper for Java, here's a commercial product that I've used. As in, I've used commercial software that used this wrapper. It works, not much else to say about it. http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Comment: Mmmm. I have no direct experience either way with java app to service.  But I am an optimistic that an app that is not using relative paths, and that requires no occasional user input should be able to become a service.    Conceptually, the Windows task scheduler or a cron service, are wrappers for the process being launched - they provide environment, authentication, etc, and may be a way of avoiding the problems that mfinni is referring to.

Comment: The problem with simply service-izing a BAT script that runs a java program is that the BAT script (and thus Java) won't properly work with restart/shutdown signals sent to/by the service.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a service wrapper for Java, here's a commercial product that I've used. As in, I've used commercial software that used this wrapper. It works, not much else to say about it. http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp